# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with the strcpy-function in c

Tags: c, algorithm, strcpy

I am trying to write a function which will read two strings `stringArray[MAX]="ABADDFDEFBFCCHCGGEHJJI"` and `popArr[MAX]="ABCDEFGHIJ"` and generate an output like this:

```
A
B-F-D-A
C-F-D-A
D-A
E-G-C-F-D-A
F-D-A
G-C-F-D-A
H-C-F-D-A
I-J-H-C-F-D-A
J-H-C-F-D-A
```

However I'm getting a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` Error. Why? This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

size_t strlstchar(const char *str, const char ch)
{
    char *chptr = strrchr(str, ch);
    return chptr - str;
}

int main(){ 
    // Input strings    
    char stringArray[MAX]="ABADDFDEFBFCCHCGGEHJJI";
    char popArr[MAX]="ABCDEFGHIJ";

    int index=2, lenpop, lentemp;
    char usedString[MAX]="";    
    char tempChar;

    lenpop    = strlen(popArr); 

    printf("%c\n", stringArray[0]); 

    for(int i=1;i<lenpop;i++){
        strcpy(usedString, stringArray);
        printf("%c", popArr[i]);
        tempChar = popArr[i];

        while(tempChar!=stringArray[0]){
            while(index%2==0){
                index = strlstchar(usedString, tempChar);
                lentemp = strlen(usedString);
                usedString[lentemp-index-1]=0;
                }   

            printf("-%c", usedString[index-1]);
            tempChar=usedString[index-1];   
            index=2;        
            }
            printf("\n");       
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem statement? It is hard to guess how does the output depend on the input.

Comment: A debugger will tell you where the seg fault occurs. Your problem statement is vague. `stringArray` seems to describe edges of a graph and your output should be paths to A. Please edit this into the question.

Comment: If you replace strcpy with strcat, segfault still occurs?

Comment: You're going to have to explain how that input is supposed to give that output.

Comment: Ignore the algorithm! I changed the question accoring asking only about the error occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segmentation violation occurs in this line:

```
    usedString[lentemp - index - 1] = 0;
```

Here, you're trying to find the index from the end, but your `strlstchar` returns the index from the beginning, although it starts searching from the end. And you want truncate the string at the found character, of course.

Replace this line with just:

```
    usedString[index] = 0;
```

and you get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks it worked for the first iteration `B-F-D-A` but afterwards the error appears again.

Comment: Hmmm. I can't reproduce that. Anyway, you seem to have found a solution.

Comment: I'm compilig with `gcc -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -static -std=c99 -pipe -o "%e" "%f" -lm` on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If I take the code from your question, just fi what I've shown above and then compile, it works. I don't see how putting the memory on the heap fixes the problem. (You never free the memory from `malloc` or `strdup`, so you have many memory leaks.) I'm also unsure why you activate the heavy optimisation for a simple program.